# getParent() and getRootView() returning null on API 19

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been having trouble fixing some bugs on pre lolipop devices and come accross this bug only on API 19 but not on API 16 or on 20,21,... haven't tested on pre 16. Then again I am not sure if its a bug but I have an XML :

```
    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <WebView
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/webviewEmbed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </WebView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

then when I get the view and try to call `getParent()` or `getRootView()` I get a null object like so :

```
WebView wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewEmbed)
((ViewGroup) wb.getParent()).removeView(wb)
```

And for some reason this raises a null pointer on API 16.
Any explanation or help would be appreciated thanks everyone

Comment: nothing wrong with xml. Could be issue with webview on api16, they moved to chromium based implementation only on api 19

Comment: @OlegBogdanov Yeah I am aware of the chromium implementation on api 19 but not sure it had something to do with a layout based method, would casting `View` to the webview object work then ?

Comment: can you share the crash stack? maybe they inject some parent between your webview and relativelayout.. Im trying to find old sources in AOSP for api16

Comment: @OlegBogdanov Actually I'm sorry this happens on API 19 but not on API 16 or 20, 21,22,23 sorry about that

Comment: any support libraries you are using? please add NPE stack for the sake of question completeness